# How can I provide Twisted with 'server.pem' when running on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ssl, twisted

I want to create a Twisted based server which listens for TLS traffic. The resulting server has to run on Windows 2016. The Python version is 3.7.

I've seen this example from the Twisted doco https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html#tls-echo-server .

Because the code is running on Windows the Certificate is not a file but hidden inside the Windows Certificate store - as a result the reference to 'server.pem' in the example can't be used directly.

Can anyone tell me how to do one of the following :

- Make use of [ssl.enum_certificates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.enum_certificates) in the standard library to come up with some equivalent to the line of code which references the 'server.pem'
- Export the server certificate from the Windows Certificate store in such a way that I can create my own 'server.pem'.
- Something else which would allow the Twisted example code to run .

---

**THINGS I HAVE READ/DONE ALREADY**

I've read a certain amount of material about this issue. Much of it is some years old and all of it was read by someone who doesn't know much about certificates.

- The doco for https://pypi.org/project/wincertstore/ .
- The doco for https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ .
- This `treq` issue which touches upon accessing certificates in Windows https://github.com/twisted/treq/issues/94 .
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896763/364088) but the file referred to is four years old and was in the pre-GIT Trac repos. I can find a file called [server.pem in the git trac repos](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/test/server.pem) which I think is the same file but almost certainly not in the form referred to by [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896763/364088).